# Advertencia de plot con reactiveFilters

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Estoy desarrollando una shiny app con R y estoy teniendo un problema con un gráfico.

Este gráfico tiene dos filtros: uno por provincia y otro por segmentación.

```
   #Filtro de segmentación por provincia
  segmento <- reactive({
    re3 <- Supertienda_rfm %>% filter(Estado==input$id_prov) %>% 
      select(segment) %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      pull()
    
    re3
  })
  
  output$id_seg <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "id_seg",
                label = "Segmento:",
                choices = segmento())
  })
  
  #Reactive box por país y segmento
  pais_re <- reactive({
    re2 <- Supertienda_rfm %>% filter(Estado==input$id_prov & segment==input$id_seg  )
    re2
  })
```

Y el código de mi gráfico es el siguiente:

```
output$fig11 <- renderPlot({
      pais_re() %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=Semestre))+
        geom_col(aes(y=Total), fill="#80b1d3")+
        geom_col(aes(y=Ganancia), fill="#fdb462")+
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=median(Supertienda_rfm$Ganancia)), color="#fc4e2a")+
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=median(Supertienda_rfm$Total)), color="#023858")+
        facet_grid(~Value)+
        ggthemes::theme_solarized()+
        labs(title = "Ventas y ganancias totales por",
             subtitle = "segmentación de clientes y provincia",
             x="",
             y="$",
             caption = "Ventas (celeste). Ganancias(naranja) ")+
        theme(plot.background = element_rect(size = 1, color = 1),
              plot.title = element_text(size = rel(0.9), face = "bold"),
              plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.9), face = "bold"),
              plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.2),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8), angle = 90),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
              axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
              axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(0.8)))
    })
```

El problema es que cuando yo comienzo a filtrar funcionan los filtros pero me sale un mensaje de advertencia cada vez que cambio los filtros:

> > Warning: Error in : Problem with filter() input ..1. i Input ..1 is Estado == input$id_prov & segment == input$id_seg. x Input ..1 must be
> > of size 10254 or 1, not size 0. 138:

Busqué y encontré que una posible respuesta se realizando un reactivePlot. Intenté hacerlo pero no me salió, directamente dejó de aparecer el gráfico.

Si alguien me puede dar un ayuda se lo agradecería; soy relativamente nueva con R.

Gracias!

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo de tu base de datos, el ui y el server, puedo intentar ayudarte